# Haskell parse error on input `let'

Tags: haskell

Im trying to run this code but I'm getting a parse error on input 'let' on:

```
 let database = tempFilm:database
```

I can't find where the problem is, could you take a look please?

```
options 7 (username, database) = do   putStrLn "******************"
                                      putStrLn "   Rate a film    "
                                      putStrLn "******************"
                                      putStrLn ""
                                      putStr "Enter the title of the film or nothing to return to the main menu: "
                                      title <- getLine
                                      if title == ""
                                        then return(username, database)
                                      else do let filmCheck = findFilm title database
                                              if filmCheck == []
                                                then do putStrLn "That film does not exists."
                                                        return (username, database) 
                                                else do putStr "Enter your rate: "
                                                        tempRate <- getLine
                                                        case reads tempRate :: [(Integer, String)] of
                                                             [(n, "")] -> do let rate = read tempRate :: Int
                                                                             let tempFilm = rateFilm username (username, rate) filmCheck
                                                                             if checkIfRated username tempFilm == True 
                                                                              then do putStrLn "You already voted for this film\n"
                                                                                      putStrLn "Do you want to modify your voted?\n"
                                                                                      putStrLn "Press y to modify or nothing to return to the main menu:"
                                                                                      input <- getLine
                                                                                      if input /= "y"
                                                                                        then return (username, database)
                                                                                      else putStrLn "Your vote will be modified."
                                                                             let database = tempFilm:database
                                                                             putStrLn "You rating has been  sumbited successfully!"
                                                                             putStrLn (displayFilm tempFilm)
                                                                             return (username, database)
```

**Edit:**
Using when

```
options 7 (username, database) = do   putStrLn "******************"
                                      putStrLn "   Rate a film    "
                                      putStrLn "******************"
                                      putStrLn ""
                                      putStr "Enter the title of the film or nothing to return to the main menu: "
                                      title <- getLine
                                      if title == ""
                                        then return(username, database)
                                      else do let filmCheck = findFilm title database
                                              if filmCheck == []
                                                then do putStrLn "That film does not exists."
                                                        return (username, database) 
                                                else do putStr "Enter your rate: "
                                                        tempRate <- getLine
                                                        case reads tempRate :: [(Integer, String)] of
                                                             [(n, "")] -> do let rate = read tempRate :: Int
                                                                             let tempFilm = rateFilm username (username, rate) filmCheck
                                                                             when (checkIfRated username tempFilm == True) $
                                                                                 do putStrLn "You already voted for this film\n"
                                                                                    putStrLn "Do you want to modify your vote?\n"
                                                                                    putStrLn "Press y to modify or nothing to return to the main menu:"
                                                                                    input <- getLine
                                                                                    if input /= "y"
                                                                                      then return (username, database)
                                                                                    else putStrLn "Your vote will be modified."
                                                                             let database = tempFilm:database
                                                                             putStrLn "You rating has been  sumbited successfully!"
                                                                             putStrLn (displayFilm tempFilm)
                                                                             return (username, database)
```

My syntax might no correct I've never use when before

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no `else` for the `if checkIfRated ... then do putStrLn "you already voted"...`

Comment: Thanks for your reply Aaron. Is there any way to write an if statement without an else? 
like (if A then blah blah)

Comment: @user3207652: In a do-block you can use [`when`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:when), e.g. `when cond $ do ...`

Comment: @user3207652 You have to import it from `Control.Monad`.

Answer (score 0):

An **if** keyword signals the beginning of an expression that has three components: the predicate (that evaluates to type Bool), the **then** branch (that evaluates to type say **A**), and the else branch (that must evaluate to type **A** also).
The type of the if **if** expression is type A, any valid Haskell type.

I quote here from the *Real World Haskell* book, Chapter 2, Types and Functions, under **Conditional Evaluation**:

> Recall that Haskell is an expression-oriented language. In an imperative language, it can make sense to omit the else branch from an if, because we’re working with statements, not expressions. However, when we’re working with expressions, an if that was missing an else wouldn’t have a result or type if the predicate evaluated to False, so it would be nonsensical.

In imperative languages the **if** statement tells the computer to execute something but it does not have to return a typed object. In Haskell it is an expression that honors the type system to avoid unexpected side effects.